# How to set up MongoDB cloud as a Source Endpoint in AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to migrate data from MongoDB cloud to Redshift, I was planning to use AWS DMS for this migration. However I am having problems setting up MongoDB cloud as a source Endpoint.

I get the following error:

Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to create new client connection Failed to connect to database., Application-Detailed-Message: Error verifying connection: 'No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve 'development-izqpz.mongodb.net'] [connection refused calling ismaster on '27017:27017']' Failed to connect to database.

I was following this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MongoDB.html from aws, but I think I am not setting up the server correctly

Comment: i guess you have the server name incorrect or your firewall needs amending. is development-izqpz.mongodb.net publically accessible? if not then you need to allow the IP address of your DMS replication instance.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the DocumentDB cluster outside its VPC? Similar issue can be found also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73306560/1636885

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, did you figure out how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Create a peering connection of your mongodb and add it to your aws vpc.